# Are arguments of unary and binary operation arguments guaranteed to be same as original data if passed by reference?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

As you know, we can provide `UnaryOperation` and `BinaryOperation` for a lot of stl functions. Arguments of these methods can be defined by value, but in a lot of cases, we pass them by reference as follows:

```
 Ret fun(const Type &a);                       // UnaryOperation
 Ret fun(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);      // BinaryOperation
```

Now I wonder if these callback arguments are **guaranteed** to be the same element as main data by standard or not. For example, is the following code valid in the standard?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <execution>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr(10);
    std::transform(std::execution::par, arr.begin(), arr.end(), arr.begin(),
                   [&arr](const int& v) -> int { return (&v - &arr[0]); });
    for (const auto& v: arr)
        std::cout << v << " ";
}
```

Because `(&v - &arr[0])` will be valid if and only if `v` refers to original elements in `arr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example as written exhibits undefined behavior. Parallel algorithms are given a dispensation to make arbitrary copies of elements of the sequence, under certain circumstances.

> **[algorithms.parallel.user]/1** Unless otherwise specified, function objects passed into parallel algorithms ... shall not ... rely on the identity of the provided objects.

> **[algorithms.parallel.exec]/3** Unless otherwise stated, implementations may make arbitrary copies of elements (with type `T`) from sequences where `is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<T>` and `is_trivially_destructible_v<T>` are true. *[Note:* This implies that user-supplied function objects should not rely on object identity of arguments for such input sequences. Users for whom the object identity of the arguments to these function objects is important should consider using a wrapping iterator that returns a non-copied implementation object such as `reference_wrapper<T>` (20.14.5) or some equivalent solution. *—end note]*

A strict reading of **[algorithms.parallel.user]/1** suggests that the user-provided function must never rely on being given the original element and not a copy. The non-normative note in **[algorithms.parallel.exec]/3** appears to suggest that it would be OK to so rely if the element type is not trivially copyable or destructible. In any case, the example uses `int` for element type, which is in fact trivially copyable and destructible, and for which the `std::transform(par)` implementation is clearly allowed to make copies.

For motivation, see [P0518r1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0518r1.html) "Allowing copies as arguments to function objects given to parallel algorithms in response to CH11"

---

Non-parallel algorithms, on the other hand, are not allowed to make copies of elements unless required by the algorithm's specification. Thus, for non-parallel `std::transform`, the user-provided function may indeed rely on being given a reference to the element of the source sequence.

> **[res.on.data.races]/5** A C++ standard library function shall not access objects indirectly accessible via its arguments or via elements of its container arguments except by invoking functions required by its specification on those container elements.

The specification of `std::transform` in **[alg.transform]** says that it should call `op(*(first1 + (i - result)))` for "every iterator `i` in the range `[result, result + N)`"; that is, it should pass the result of dereferencing the iterator into the source sequence directly to the user-provided function.